# Java - not getting "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" when expected

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the following code

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String one = "x";
        if(one.charAt(one.indexOf('x')+1)== 'p'){
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at test.main(test.java:4)*

I expect this to happen and my understanding is that it's happening because the String only has 1 index (0) so it is not possible to locate the character at index 1

```
one.charAt(one.indexOf('x')+1)== 'p'
```

If my understanding is correct, I can't understand why this other program doesn't have the same problem

```
class XClass{
   boolean doubleX(String str){
      boolean is = false;
      int indexes = str.length()-1;
      if(str.indexOf('x')== indexes){
         is = false;
      }else if(str.charAt(str.indexOf('x')+1)=='x'){//same code as the program above
         is = true;
      }
      return is;
   }
}

public class ImplementXClass{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      XClass Xmen = new XClass();
      boolean result = Xmen.doubleX("x");
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

This program compiles successfully even though the method parameter is a String with one index ("x").

- How can the program run this line str.charAt(str.indexOf('x')+1)=='x' if there's no index 1.
- Shouldn't it fail to compile as the first program?
- What am I missing?

Comment: Because that code never gets executed.  And there is no compile error in the first program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `str` being `"x"`, the `else if` isn't even run.

The `if` condition

```
if(str.indexOf('x') == indexes)
```

is `true`, because `str.indexOf('x')` returns `0`, and `indexes` is also `0` -- `str.length() - 1`.

So, `is` is set to `false` and the `else if` condition is never evaluated.  Therefore, no `IndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Because your one character String passes the first `if` condition,

```
int indexes = str.length()-1; // length is 1, 1-1 is 0.
if(str.indexOf('x')== indexes){ // str.indexOf('x') == 0
  is = false; // <-- hits this.
```

Your `else if` is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

```
  //str = "x"
  int indexes = str.length()-1; //indexes = 0;
  if(str.indexOf('x')== indexes){  //evals to true, because the index of x is 0 in string "x"
     is = false;
  } else { 
     //... never executes because above evaluated to true
```